# R: How do I use a range stored in a list as part of a function in a for loop

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
x = c(1,2,5,6)
x = rbind(x,c(4,3,6,5))
x = rbind(x,c(3,7,6,5))

y = 1:2
z = 3:4
variables = list(y,z)

p = 1
for(i in variables){ 
  assign(paste("tbl",p,sep="")) = table(x[,i])
  p = p + 1
}

tbl1
tbl2
```

How do I get the for loop to recognize i as 1:2 and 3:4 so that I get 2 tables returned from the loop named "tbl1" and "tbl2"?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code has a problem, please review it and publish your specific question instead of saying "correct my code"

Comment: you are resetting `x = 1`, the `table()` will not use the matrix at the top.

Comment: @ Neal thanks, updated.

Comment: try `assign(paste("tbl",p,sep=""), table(x[,i]))` instead

Comment: Can you also please write down what do you expect to see in tbl1 and tbl2?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what output you expect, so I can just guess. First, I assumed that you meant to `cbind`, rather than `rbind` the vectors in `x`. Then I further assumed that the indices of `x` within your `table`-operation referred to the rows rather than the columns (otherwise the indices would be out of bounds).

Here is what you could do:

```
## Your data:
x <-  cbind(c(1,2,5,6), c(4,3,6,5), c(3,7,6,5))

## Your indices
variables <- list(y = 1:2, z = 3:4)

## Your loop:
for (i in seq(along = variables)){ 
    assign(paste0("tbl", i), table(x[variables[[i]],])) 
}  

tbl1
# 
# 1 2 3 4 7 
# 1 1 2 1 1 

tbl2
# 
# 5 6 
# 3 3
```